# How can I create a one-to-many relationship with Spring and thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to create a "Product" class which has multiple "Tags" as a collection. So a one-to-many database whereas Product is "one" and Tags is "many".

The Tags will be defined in the HTML as an Input field and divided by spaces. For example "tag1 tag2 tag3".

My question now is: How can I retrieve the string from the input field and append them as a Collection to my product object?

What I have so far:

Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int barcode;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Tag> tags;

...Getter & Setter
```

Tag

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private String tagname;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

...Getter & Setter
```

ProductsController: I tried to add Tag objects as a test but that throws errors that the Tag table does not exist

```
@PostMapping("/add")
        public String add(@Valid Product product, BindingResult result, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("responseMessage", result);
            if(!result.hasErrors()) {
//I tried to add a static collection to the product object, but it throws errors
                Collection<Tag> col = new ArrayList<>();
                col.add(new Tag("test"));
                col.add(new Tag("test2"));
                product.setTags(col);

                productRepository.save(product);
            }
            model.addAttribute("products",productRepository.findAll());
            return "products-add";
        }
```

Comment: I think in your product class. private List<Tag> tags; its missing

Comment: I forgot to copy that, it's just below the @Onetomany annotation
public Collection<Tag> tags;

Answer (score 3):

As you have the tags separated by space. First of all you need to make a String Array of tags using regex as shown below.

```
String tags = "tag1 tag2 tag3";
String[] tagArr = tags.split("\\s+");
```

Now you need to create a repository as below.

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {
    Tag findByTagname(String tagname);
}
```

Create an interface for TagService.

```
public interface TagService {
    Tag findByTagname(String tagname);
}
```

Create an implementation of TagService class

```
@Service
public class TagServiceImpl implements TagService{

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Override
    public Tag findByTagname(String tagname) {
        return tagRepository.findByTagname(tagname);
    }
}
```

Now fetching Tag by name is completed. Autowire your TagService into your controller class

```
@Autowire
private TagService tagService;
```

Add the below code to your controller.

```
String tags = "tag1 tag2 tag3";
String[] tagArr = tags.split("\\s+"); 

List<Tag> tagList = new ArrayList<Tag>();

for (String tagname : tagArr) {
    Tag tag = tagService.findbyTagname(tagname);
    tagList.add(tag);
}
```

Now when you save your product class. Set this list of tag into your it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must have a ProductService class in your service layer annotated with @Service.
2. You must create a method annotated with @Transactional in ProductService class
3. Your method must read all tags of a product and transform it to any collection you want.
4. Don't do it inside Controller. It is actually bad place to do same things.

Comment: How does the usage of Service layer work? Do you have an example code perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running this for first time and your database does not have table named Tag. Please make sure hibernate property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to 'update' which will automatically create required tables first before doing any insert of data.

And for converting string value tags separated by space, just use string.split() method which gives you array and then convert it to List to be set in Product object.